# ¿como puedo colocar Acentos y la letra ñ en web api 2?

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

Uso web api 2 de microsoft.
   tengo un problema cuando devuelvo un 401 Unauthorized, los caracteres como la ñ o acentos no se muestran correctamente

codigo:

```
private IHttpActionResult resultado()
{ 
return Unauthorized(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization","Usuario 
o Contraseña incorrecto")); 
}
```

respuesta del encabezado:

```
401, Unauthorized
pragma: no-cache
date: Thu, 17 May 2018 15:07:52 GMT
www-authenticate: Authorization Usuario o ContraseÃ±a incorrectos
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
cache-control: no-cache
```

los caracteres de la letra ñ no salen como debe ser.
esto pasa cuando uso Unauthorized porque la respuesta viaja en el header.
¿hay alguna manera de resolverlo?
la idea es que el header reconozca la letra ñ y acentos.

Comment: con colocar en el header algo como text/html;charset=utf-8, creo que funcionaria

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/daniem/2009/12/01/acentos-y-ees-no-se-muestran-correctamente/